# How to transfer data from view to controller action function using jquery in Web2py

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, view, web2py

I need some help in transferring data from a view to a controller action function. My case is as follows:
I have a table with checkboxes. Each table entry corresponds to a request with a request id. the user will select some checkboxes and then click the 'Approve' button. On clicking the button, the jQuery script must find all selected request ids and send them to a controller function.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
function get_selected_req(){
    var ids = [];  
    jQuery('#sortTable1 tr').has(":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr");// Finds the closest row<tr> 
        $tds = $row.find("td:nth-child(2)"); // Finds the 2nd <td> element
        ids.push($tds.text());
        $('#out').text(ids.join('|'));    
    });
}
```

I have to send the array 'ids' to a controller function that can then process the requests using the ids. But I don't know how to do that. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Update:
I have written the ajax code in the view. I am only sending one id at a time. The code is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "{{=URL(r=request, c='admin',f='approve_request')}}",
                data: $tds.text(),
                success:  function(data){  alert('yay');
                                        tab_refresh(); 
                                        check_resource(data);

                                        }
            });
```

i am bit stuck on how to parse the data in the controller. Here is the code:

```
def approve_request():
    request_id=request.args[0]
    enqueue_vm_request(request_id);
    session.flash = 'Installation request added to queue'
    redirect(URL(c='admin', f='list_all_pending_requests'))
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Use push to `push` a value to a array,join the array with a delimiter, split the resulting data in the serverside

```
ids.push($tds.text());
$('#out').text(ids.join('|'));
```

note: `#out` should be hidden input

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I have made the changes in the code. But I don't know the code to transfer the data from view to controller i.e. I need to call an action function using a URL.

Comment: @AnmolAnand use a simple form submit

Comment: or a ajax request

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
You can pass any value to function by simply calling a function in javascript. 

Client side: 

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "HomePage/HandleOperations",
     data: {operations: operationCollection},
     success: function (data) { alert("SUCCESS"); }
});

and declare a class server side like this:

public class Operation
{
  public int Index[];
  }

then you can have this action:

public void HandleOperations(Operation[] operations)
{
}

else you can try this option 

var selectedCatId = $(this).val();
                var details = baseUrl+"/controllername/controllerfunctionname/"+selectedCatId;

and in controller 

public function controllerfunctionname(array of ids[] ){

}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I see that i need to use ajax but isn't this ASP.net code. I am working on web2py with python. But i'll do the needful conversion. Thanks!

Comment: Its matter of great pleasure let me know need any further help.

Answer (score 0):

When you post data to web2py, the resulting variables can be found in `request.post_vars` (also in `request.vars`, which is a combination of `request.post_vars` and `request.get_vars`). To send the data in the proper format, you should send a Javascript object rather than a single value or an array (the keys of the object will become the keys of `request.post_vars`).

If you want to send a single `id` at a time:

```
$.ajax({
  ...,
  data: {id: $tds.text()},
  ...
});
```

Then in your web2py controller:

```
def approve_request():
    request_id = request.post_vars.id
```

To send an array of ids:

```
$.ajax({
  ...,
  data: {ids: ids},
  ...
});
```

Note, when you send an array via jQuery as above, jQuery converts the key from "ids" to "ids[]", so to retrieve the array in web2py:

```
def approve_request():
    request_ids = request.post_vars['ids[]']
```